# My laravel & ajax form is returning error 419

Tags: ajax, laravel

So e.preventDefault() isn't working for some reason. I have a foreach that repeats a question form. I tried onsubmit on the form & onclick on the submit button alternately. it isn't working for some reason.

here is my form

```
  @php
     $x = 0;
  @endphp
  @foreach ($knowledges as $know)
                   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="answers">الاجابه</label>
                        <form action="{{ route('user.knowledge.store', [$know->id]) }}" method="post"
                            onsubmit="handleForm(event,$i)" id="answerForm{{ $i }}">

                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}" name="user_id" id="user_id">

                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $know->id }}" name="knowledge_id" id="question_id">


                            @for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        {{ $know->answer[$i]['value'] }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[{{ $i }}][key]" value="1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endfor
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button" type="submit"> سجل
                                الاجابه</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>



                <hr>
                @php
                    $i++;
                @endphp
            @endforeach
```

Here is my ajax

```
  function handleForm(event, id) {
            event.preventDefault();

            formId = 'answerForm' + id;
            var method = $(formId).attr('method');
            var action = $(formId).attr('action');

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: action,
                data: $(formId).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Here is a picture of the error
[image]

Comment: Add csrf token inside the form **@csrf**

Comment: I mean i shouldn't need that because i am doing it through the ajax setup. I really think the problem is with my event.preventDefault()

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is a javascript thing. IDK how that would relate to your issue. You should check the actual response of that request. It should tell you what is going wrong if you have Laravel properly configured. I also cant see the complete Request headers in your screenshot but I suppose they contain the csrf-token.

Comment: The controller returns a JSON message of "its all done". so really it shouldn't be a factor here. i have  <meta name="csrf-token" id="csrf" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> in my html header and i am loading the csrf token from there.

Comment: Yeah it was the CSRF Token. Thanks guys <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following script next to jquery library and before your script

```
<!-- check Xsrf Token -->
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
```